# How can I get my ArrayList in my JSF to dynamically print?

Tags: jsf, arraylist, datatable

When I run the JSF with the items listed, I get the first part to come up where I can enter in details successfully, but they won't show up on the screen like I want them to! Can you guys please help:

Here's my index.xhtml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF Tester</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            First name: <h:inputText value="#{PersonController.current.firstName}"/>
            Last name: <h:inputText value="#{PersonController.current.lastName}"/>
            Birth date: (mm-dd-yyyy) <h:inputText value="#{PersonController.current.date}">
                <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="full" type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit Person" action="#{PersonController.savePerson()}" />

            <h:dataTable var="persons" value="#{PersonController.current}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                        #{PersonController.current.firstName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>               
                        #{PersonController.current.lastName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                        #{PersonController.current.date}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here is my class containing the ArrayList:

```
/**
 $ Id: PersonController.java v1.0, 7/16/2014
 $ Name: $
 */
package org.usd.csci.person.jsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@ManagedBean(name="PersonController")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonController implements Serializable {

    Person current = new Person();
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of PersonController
     */
    public PersonController() {
    }

    public Person getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void savePerson() {
        persons.add(current);
        current = new Person();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you `want them to`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the datatable in a wrong way. It should be like the below.

`value` parameter should address the `ArrayList`. In your case `PersonController.persons`.

`var` parameter is used to address the `Person` objects in `persons` list. You can name it whatever you want.

To access a property of `Person` object You will use this `var` parameter. For example if you set `var` as
`var = "variableName"`, You can access the properties of a `Person` object using `variableName.firstName` `variableName.lastName` etc.

```
<h:dataTable var="person" value="#{PersonController.persons}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                        #{person.firstName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>               
                        #{person.lastName}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
                        #{person.date}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Is there a way I can get the date to print out as mm-dd-yyyy? I have the code set